# What is the equivalent of a factory in Angular2?

Tags: angularjs, angular

So I am used to using factories & services in Angular.

I am reading through the Angular2 docs and I don't see any equivalent of a factory. What is the equivalent for Angular2?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Factories, services, constants and values are all gone in Angular2. Angular2 is radically and fundamentally different from the classic Angular. In Angular2, the core concepts are

- components
- dependency injection
- binding

The idea of services, factories, providers and constants has been criticized in Angular 1. It was difficult to choose between one. Removing them simplifies things a bit.

In the original Angular, you would define a service like so

```
app.service('BookService', ['$http', '$q', BookService]);
function BookService($http, $q){
  var self = this;
  var cachedBooks;
  self.getBooks = function(){
    if (cachedBooks) {
      return $q.when(cachedBooks);
    }
    return $http.get('/books').then(function(response){
      cachedBooks = response.data.books;
      return cachedBooks;
    })
  }
}
```

Angular2 significantly leverages ES6 syntax to make the code more readable and easier to understand.

One new keyword in ES6 is `class`, which can be thought of as a service.

> ES6 classes are a simple sugar over the prototype-based OO pattern. Having a single convenient declarative form makes class patterns easier to use, and encourages interoperability. Classes support prototype-based inheritance, super calls, instance and static methods and constructors.

Here's how that same code might look in Angular2

```
import {HttpService, Promise}  from '../Angular/Angular2';
export class BookService{
    $http, $q, cachedBooks;
    constructor($http: HttpService, $q: Promise) {
        this.$http = $http;
        this.$q = $q
    }
    getBooks() {
    if (this.cachedBooks) {
        return this.$q.when(this.cachedBooks);
    }
    return this.$http.get('/books').then(function(data) {
        this.cachedBooks = data.books;
        return this.cachedBooks;
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: why would you say **services** are gone in Angular 2? It is still a big section as a general concept in the official tutorial: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html

Comment: Can you show in the answer how to create a shared object?

Comment: Following on from @zoonman, class factories are also needed to hide the DI dependencies of classes as demonstrated here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#!#factory-provider

Comment: I don't think this answers the original question. Even if the 'factory' alias is not implemented in angular the pattern is still viable and significantly distinguished from a normal service pattern.

Comment: I think as es6 has a 'class' keyword, we can just use class to replace factory. A factory is a lot like a class

Answer (score 15):

@Richard Hamilton's answer is appreciated and in addition to that there are few points to note.

For Factories,Service, and etc, in Angular2 we have **service (or shared service)**. we have to make our service `Injectable` in order to use it.

NOTE: This code belongs to beta version and not RC.

```
import {Component, Injectable,Input,Output,EventEmitter} from 'angular2/core'
import {Router} from 'angular2/router';
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';

export interface ImyInterface {
   show:boolean;
}

@Injectable()      <---------------------------- Very Important
export class sharedService {  <----------------- Service Name
  showhide:ImyInterface={show:true};

  constructor(http:Http;router:Router)
  {
    this.http=http;
  }     
  change(){
        this.showhide.show=!this.showhide.show;
  }
}
```

If I want to use everywhere in my app, then I have to inject this service in bootstrap function like this,

```
bootstrap(App, [HTTP_PROVIDERS,sharedService    <--------Name Injection
      ROUTER_PROVIDERS,bind(APP_BASE_HREF).toValue(location.pathname)
]);
```

This way it creates single instance of your service. If you don't want to go with single instance, what you can do is - you can use `Providers:[sharedService]` metadata in you `@component` decorator.

Then, use it in your one of components like this,

```
export class TheContent {
  constructor(private ss: sharedService) {  <--------Injection dependency of your newly created service
    console.log("content started");
  }
  showhide() {
    this.ss.change();  <----- usage
  }
}
```

[Check working example here](https://plnkr.co/edit/9VhDW442Keld9OTSA63O?p=preview)

Comment: `bind(...).toXxx(...)` is deprecated syntax. Use instead `provide(..., {useXxx: ...})`

Comment: Thanks for the update. I din't note it while writing this stuff.

Answer (score 9):

I don't know what factories do exactly in Angular1 but in Angular2 there is `useFactory`:

```
{ 
  provide: SomeClass, 
  useFactory: (dep1, dep2) => (x) => new SomeClassImpl(x, dep1, dep2),
  deps: [Dep1, Dep2]
}
```

to provide your own instance construction logic if the default doesn't match your needs.

You can also inject a factory to create new instances yourself:

```
/* deprecated or removed depending on the Angular version you are using */
provide(SomeClass, {
    useFactory: (dep1, dep2) => {
        (x) => new SomeClassImpl(x, dep1, dep2), 
    },
    deps: [Dep1, Dep2]
})
```

```
constructor(@Inject(SomeClass) someClassFactory: any) {
  let newSomeClass = someClassFactory(1);
}
```

Argument x must have type assignment, otherwise angular doesn't know how to deal with it.

```
class SomeClassImpl {
  constructor(x: number, dep1: Dep1, dep2: Dep2){}
}
```

Comment: should deps property be in the same scope as useFactory?

Comment: As far as I remember I answered a similar question with a Plunker. Would have been a good idea here as well :-/. Thanks again for the fix.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Looking at `let newSomeClass = someClassFactory(1);` ( middle snipped) - in the CTOR  , the `someClassFactory: any` is already(!) invoked , returning already `new SomeClassImpl`. So why do you invoke it again in `let newSomeClass = someClassFactory(1);` ? Am I missing something ?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. The update for the "new" syntax to register providers I forgot a `(x) =>`. The intention was to inject a factory function, not the result of the factory function.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a new instance of a service in some component you need to provide it in that component like this:

```js
@Component({
  selector:    'hero-list',
  templateUrl: './hero-list.component.html',
  providers:  [ HeroService ]
})
```

This will generate a new instance of the `HereService` as a factory does.