# angular 2: multiple instances of a service with different factories

Tags: angular

Ok so basically I have the scenario where a service is very similar except for some initialization variables, which is the perfect candidate for factory.

However, I can't figure out how to use multiple services in the same component/module where each service has been initialized with a different factory?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the point? Why not just `new MyClass()`?

Comment: You can use a factory like shown in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38482357/angular2-how-to-use-multiple-instances-of-same-service/38483406#38483406 which takes parameters (like the `x` in the example.

Answer (score -1):

Service in angular 2 is a class, So you can easily do something like

```
let firstServiceInstance = new myServiceClass(...some arguments);
let secondServiceInstance = new myServiceClass(...some arguments);
let thiredServiceInstance = new myServiceClass(...some arguments);
```

And every of the above variables will hold reference to the service.