# Angular: Multiple instances of the same service

Tags: angular, typescript

### The Problem

I use a [service](https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-ng2-components/blob/525f0a06dbeebec9ed9be3c52cc2ab002c58cb54/lib/core/services/search.service.ts) of a third-party module for my Angular application. This service includes a [method](https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-ng2-components/blob/525f0a06dbeebec9ed9be3c52cc2ab002c58cb54/lib/core/services/search.service.ts#L74) that handles the REST-calls to the backend.

The service is used in two different components of my Angular application. However, it can happen that both components send a request nearly at the same time and - since the REST-calls are asynchronous - the results get mixed up.

To make it more clear, here is a simplified version of the third party service:

```js
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ThirdPartyService {

  dataLoaded: Subject<Result> = new Subject();

  callBackend(request: RequestBody): Observable<Result> {
    const promise = this.someJSLibrary.call(request);

    promise.then((result: Result) => {
      this.dataLoaded.next(result);
    });

    return from(promise);
  }
}
```

When both of my components call `callBackend()` nearly at the same time, it seems as if their results would overwrite each other the field `dataLoaded`.

### The Question

How can I prevent this behavior? Is there a straightforward way to create multiple instances of the same service and limit their scope on one component?

I found some [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38483406/9291522) on StackOverflow that recommend using a custom factory function. Is this really the recommended way of solving such a common problem?

Comment: By Default, Services are singleton, however if you provide service inside component's provider a unique instance will be created solely for that component and won't be shared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in the [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/providers#limiting-provider-scope-with-components). I'll post it here. May it help someone someday.

The simple answer is, you have to limit the scope of the service to the component by including it in the `provider` array of the `@Component` decorator:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-component.component.scss'],
  providers: [ ThirdPartyService ]  // <--- this is the solution
})
export class MyComponent {
  // ...
}
```