# "Maximum call stack size exceeded" in Angular 9 ng build --prod for a library

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-packagr

I have a library that I'm able to compile with Angular 9. But if I change the flag to --prod, which practically makes `"enableIvy": false` then I get

> [error] RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
>
> at Object.pathIsRelative (...\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:5778:34)
>
> at tryLoadModuleUsingPathsIfEligible (...\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:28346:37)
>
> at tryLoadModuleUsingOptionalResolutionSettings (...\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:28334:24)
>
> at tryResolve (...\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:28479:28)
>
> at ...\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:28471:69
>
> at Object.forEach (...\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:309:30)
>
> at nodeModuleNameResolverWorker (...\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:28471:25)
>
> at nodeModuleNameResolver (...\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:28464:16)
>
> at Object.resolveModuleName (...\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:28238:30)
>
> at CompilerHostAdapter.getMetadataFor (...\node_modules@angular\compiler-cli\src\metadata\bundler.js:567:37)

I introduced a console debug message in `function tryLoadModuleUsingPathsIfEligible(extensions, moduleName, loader, state)` function and it seems to be a loop with approximately 20 `moduleName`s. I have to mention that I do NOT have any circular dependency warning if I compile without `--prod` flag.

*Update:* I fixed the circular dependencies and I have no more warnings of sort.

Comment: try resolve circular dependency, (if it's about inject) this SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46832072/how-to-solve-the-circular-dependency or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58749172/angular-circular-dependency-warning SO (it's about change modules) can be help you

Comment: @Eliseo I fixed the circular dependencies in my project, but I still get the same error.

Comment: @AdrianBer, have you managed to solve this issue?

Comment: I had circular dependencies caused by my IDE automatically adding references to modules and components before I changed some things around.  Use git diff or something to check all changes related to imports, exports, and declarations in your modules.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem with `angular 12.1.1`, I had no circular dependenicies, the solutution was to change `"enableIvy: false"` to `"compilationMode": "partial"`.

See [angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries#transitioning-libraries-to-partial-ivy-format).

Comment: setting enableIvy to true in angularCompilerOptions of the tsconfig I was using solved the issue for me

Answer (score 4):

Try deleting unnecessary imports, if anything like this:

> 'A' module imports 'B' module and vice versa

Answer (score 4):

In my case, with Angular 16, I've accidentally added a Component (non-standalone) to `imports` (instead of `declarations`):

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    TranslateModule,
    AuthModule,
    RouterModule,
    HeaderComponent, // <- invalid import of a Component
  ],
  declarations: [AvatarComponent],
  exports: [AvatarComponent],
  providers: [],
})
export class SharedHeaderModule {}
```

Additionally, sometimes re-running `ng serve` is required.

Comment: This is also a case where this error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

First, remove node_modules and reinstall dependencies - this is a just in case solution. Generally, what happens is

- Self Import in a module
- Cycle dependency, cycle imports
- recursive call with no termination

Be very careful to the 2 points in the beginning, as angular generally not showing that something is wrong in the imports. That may be a good reason for call stack size explosion. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Facing the same issue, different cause: I was trying to import and export an Angular Component directly in a module (It was intended to be declared and exported by other module, and then this module would be imported+exported in the first one).

Answer (score 0):

In the end, aber `rm -rf node_modules` I also needed to do `npm cache clean --force` - also I made sure I really had all dependencies updated. (Not sure which of those things did the trick)

Answer (score 0):

Error occurred for me when the `forwardRef` line below somehow got into my ContentNgModule file.

```
imports: [
    CommonModule,
    forwardRef(() => ContentNgModule)
]
```

Answer (score -1):

Been facing the same issue, in my case there was index.ts with invalid export

```
export * from './'
```

Fixed it and it build again with ng build

Comment: How did you fix it?