# Angular use multiple instances of service of parent component to child

Tags: angular, service, components, angularjs-injector

I've seen this thread: [Using multiple instances of the same service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38482357/using-multiple-instances-of-the-same-service). Is it possible to use same multiple instance of a service from parent to children?

For example, I have an `ElementService` in `ParentComponent` and have 2 instances of that service

```
{ provide: 'instance1', useClass: ElementService},
{ provide: 'instance2', useClass: ElementService},
```

How should I use `instance1` in `Child1Component` and `instance2` in `Child2Component`?

Answer (score 1):

You can inject a named provider in the constructor of each child component (and in the parent constructor as well) :

#### Child1Component

```js
constructor(@Inject('instance1') private service: ElementService) { }
```

#### Child2Component

```js
constructor(@Inject('instance2') private service: ElementService) { }
```

Here is a working example with a counter : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-usorby?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild1%2Fchild1.component.ts

Comment: Hi Gerome, thanks but what I need is that the 2 instances should be declared in parent because parent will also subscribe to the 2 instances of the service. In your example, AppComponent will also listen for the changes in DataService instances of child1 and child2.

Comment: inject the providers inside the parent component too. I updated the stackblitz example.

Comment: hi, are you able to answer this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64274610/angular-parent-component-use-different-instance-of-child-component-service

Comment: hello, the answer already included in issue(adding the service as a provider directly into the component metadata) should work.

Answer (score 1):

When you specify providers in a component's decorator, the providers that are injected become specific to that component see [Angular - Providing dependencies](https://angular.io/guide/providers)

This is also helpful info about [dependency injection](https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection)

So just specify the service in both of the component's providers array and you should have unique instances of the service in both components.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-page',
    templateUrl: './page.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./page.component.scss'],
    providers: [
        ElementService
    ]
})
export class PageComponent implements OnInit {...
```