# Coding an angular REST call shared by multiple controllers

Tags: angularjs, rest, dictionary

This question has been asked before but this is more of what style to use.  Currently we have several different controllers, and we keep making a REST call to get information. For example, `$http.get('/allusers')`. After we make this call, we create a user map to access each of these users. It works great but I don't like how we have to manually do this every time we need user information from the different controllers.

What I'd like is a shared object that has all the user information as a map and a shared function that will make the call and create/update the map.

This is where I start to get confused. What is the best and efficient way to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a Factory or a Service 
as I tried to explain here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39933229/1005137

You may also want to cache the response from your $http request with the following:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

A `service` would be appropriate to use in this case. This would allow you to inject it into controllers, directives and components.

```
angular
  .module('myApp')
  .service('userService', UserService);

UserService.$inject = ['$http'];
function UserService ($http) {
   var service = this;

   service.getAllUsers = function () {
        return $http.get('/allusers');
   }
}
```

This would then allow you to inject and use in a controller

```
function UserController(userService) {
    userService.getAllUsers().then(function (response) {
        // response.data has your goods
    });
}
```