# Angular 2: how to share a non-module level service across different routes

Tags: angularjs, angular-router

I have a service `ServiceA` which has its own states (instance variables, etc) and in my module I have multiple instances of service `ServiceA`.

```
@Injectable()
export class ServiceA { 
  // It defines instance variables.
}
```

Since I need to have multiple instances of `ServiceA`, I am not able to make it a module-level component.

In `ComponentB` instantiate a `ServiceA` instance and can potentially change its state:

```
@Component({
  providers = [ServiceA],
})
export class ComponentB {
  // changes the state of ServiceA.
}
```

Also in the HTML template of `ComponentB` I have a route to `ComponentC`, which needs to access the same `ServiceA` instance:

```
<a routerLink="/path_to_component_c"></a>
```

And here is the definition of `ComponentC`:

```
@Component({
  providers = [],
})
export class ComponentC {
  // accesses ServiceA.
}
```

If `ServiceA` was a module-level component, there won't be issues sharing it across `ComponentB` and `ComponentC`, since they are both in the same module. However, since `ServiceA` is injected into `ComponentB` directly, I am not able to do so anymore. Note that every time only one `ComponentC` will be created and `ComponentC` is created after `ComponentB`.

Is there a way to share data between `ComponentB` and `ComponentC`? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use `ServiceA` as a *factory* rather than a singleton. This can be accomplished with a [*Factory Provider*](https://angular.io/api/core/FactoryProvider).

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37517575/2387291) answer.

> Is there a way to share data between ComponentB and ComponentC? Thanks!

There are a few ways. A service is one (yes, you can have a service for instances of your factory!). If `ComponentC` is a child of `ComponentB`, you could use an [*input*](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction).