# Transitively inject injection token into a service defined in library, used within an angular application

Tags: angular, angular7, angular8, angular-dependency-injection

I've created an angular library, say `library1`, which defines and exposes a service `APIService`. The `APIService` has a constructor argument (`URL: string`), which is injected with an Injection token defined as,

`const URL_TOKEN = new InjectionToken<string>('API_BASE_URL');`

I use this `library1` in yet another library, say `library2`, i.e. I inject the `APIService` within a component called `LoginComponent`.

Now I have a full-fledged angular application, and I use the LoginComponent from library2, and I wish to `provide` the value of `URL` from the application.

I wonder if there is a way to achieve this. I'm also not sure how to expose `URL_TOKEN` from `library1` all the way to the angular application in a nice way.

### Update

When I try to inject API_BASE_URL as,

`providers: [ {provide: new InjectionToken<string>('API_BASE_URL'), useValue: 'http://endpoint'} ]`

I get an exception in the browser: `ERROR NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[InjectionToken API_BASE_URL]:`

Comment: take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56707222/1209097) it might solve your problem

Comment: Thanks @ysf, I checked it. Anyway ended up exporting URL_TOKEN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up exporting URL_TOKEN all the way. After going through bunch of resources (stack overflow questions, github posts, angular docs etc.), that seems to be the right way to do it.